# Python regex for email addresses, need to weed out dot dash

Tags: python, regex

I have created this regular expression to weed out obviously wrong email addresses. For my large data set it works for 98% of cases.

```
pattern = re.compile('^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$')
```

The part where the problem is is here:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)
```

It is okay if an email address has a dash in the domain, or a period, but I don't want these two symbols to be allowed consecutively such as `.- or -.`

For example, these are okay (and should match the regex):

```
chris@data.services.com
chris@data-services.com
```

But this is not (and should not yield a match):

```
chris@data.-services.com
```

I have read extensively and tried all kinds of options around creating another group in the regex like `([\.]|[\-])?` to no avail. Can someone help?

Comment: Negative look-ahead assertion.... `^(?!.*\.-.*$|.*-\..*$)([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$` , https://regex101.com/r/qH7eT1/1

Comment: what about `..` or `--`

Comment: If not then `^(?!.*[.-]{2,}.*$)([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+‌​)([a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$`

Comment: This was going to be my next question because I noticed that my regex allows `.. and --` Thanks!

Comment: i just thought about that :)

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a perfectly reasonable question that is well constructed and very understandable. I have read extensively and tried all kinds of options around creating another group in the regex, as stated in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [negative look ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) here

```
^(?!.*\.-.*$|.*-\..*$)([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/qH7eT1/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

More specific one will be

```
^(?![a-zA-Z0-9._@-]*\.-[a-zA-Z0-9._@-]*$|[a-zA-Z0-9._-@]*-\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-@]*$)([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$
```

---

Or in case `..`, `--`, `...`, etc. are not allowed then you can use

```
^(?![a-zA-Z0-9._@-]*[.-]{2,}[a-zA-Z0-9._@-]*$)([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$
```

Comment: When I paste this last one into regex101, I get the error "Text range out of order".

Comment: I think I fixed it by escaping a couple of the dashes. i.e. `^(?![a-zA-Z0-9._\-@]*[.-]{2,}[a-zA-Z0-9._\-@]*$)([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)([a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$`

Comment: @ChrisNielsen :  fixed, otherwise you need to move it to at the end